# Need to replace accented /diacritics/non ASCII characters in a fixed width file with Space

Tags: perl, shell, unix, sed, awk

**Need to replace accented /diacritics/non ASCII characters in a fixed width file with Space using shell scripting/awk/perl**

We have a fixed width file which has got accented /diacritics/non ASCII characters in a fixed width file. This file is generated by extracting data from database and spooling it to file. Main issue here is when we query database these accented /diacritics/non ASCII characters are visible on database client console. But when we extract this data to a file and open the file in putty box, we are unable to see those characters.

For example, we see as JEANNOýýýýýýL in the database console, but in putty box we see it as JEANNOL

To fix this I tried below approach.

Used od -An -tu1 command to find ASCII values for each character in file. For all these accented /diacritics/non ASCII characters i am getting ASCII value as null which i am replacing it with ASCII character of Space. Then I am printing characters for those ASCII values. Here issue is some spaces which are are genuine in input record are getting removed and messing up column structure for this fixed width file.

I want to maintain same line length for each record in fixed width file even after i replace ASCII value of accented characters with Space.

Can i get help on this to fix ?

Thanks

Comment: What does "open the file in putty box" mean? I think you might mean PuTTY the telnet/ssh client, but to my knowledge, it doesn't open files.

Comment: @ikegami Putty box in the sense vi editor available in it. Or if i do cat on file.

Comment: Is the db client and `cat` being run from the session? What bytes are in the file where you expect "JEANNOýýýýýýL"? What encoding is listed in your PuTTY sessions's Window/Translation/"Received data assumed to be"?

Comment: Yes it is run from the session. Below is the Character set encoding  ISO-8859-1:1998 (Latin-1, West Europe). Its unicode mode.

Comment: What about my second question?

Comment: We are using ETL tool to read data from Database and write to file. Source database has these special characters displayed from DB client tool. In ETL tool we have encoding as ISO-8859-1 Western European. I did not understand "What bytes are in the file where you expect "JEANNOýýýýýýL"?".. Can you elaborate this?

Answer (score 1):

I think your database contains utf8 encoded chars which are not handled by your ETL process.

Best way to handle this is to change your ETL process and remove these characters.

Alternate way is to use these regexps. For the second one you need to use recent Perl (I used 5.10.1).

```
cat file | perl -lne 's!\x{00}! !g;print' > good_file. <-- this will replace every null to space

cat file | perl -lne 's![^[:ascii:]]! !g;print' > good_file. <-- this will replace every non ascii char to space
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you also please let me know how i can replace a range of ASCII characters or a specific ASCII character from file with a space. Also we have Perl 5.8.4 with us and you are mentioning second command works only with Perl 5.10.1. Is there any other way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

one way by using sed

```
sed -i 's:[^[:print:]]:g' infile
```